# Optimized query for IN operator with multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table structure

```
batch_id    id  value
877         10  ABC
877         41  XYZ
877         23  VPN
855         10  ABC
866         41  XYZ
```

I want batch id for which following both conditions are true
id = 10 and value = ABC
id = 41 and value = XYZ

In above example I want 877 as output.

I have written query like:

```
SELECT final_table.id
FROM
(
    select C.value , C.id
    FROM C
    WHERE (C.id, C.value) IN ((10, 'ABC'), (41, 'XYZ'))
) AS final_table
GROUP BY final_table .id
HAVING COUNT(final_table .id) > 1
```

As I don't have too much knowledge of sql please suggest is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag the correct dbms.

Comment: I think your query is correct, although you do not need to use a subquery.

Comment: is AND-OR combination is fast and optimized than IN operator?

Comment: Do some tests and measure time ...